# Remove closest word before occurrence of a substring in PHP

Tags: php, string, substring, str-replace

Here's an example of what I'm trying to figure out. I have a couple of strings, both illustrating two different cases.

**Case 1**: Dietetics/Nutrition, Fitness, And Health

**Case 2**: Atmospheric Science/Meteorology

I'd like to write a single function that removes the word on the *right* side of the "/". So cases 1 and 2 would turn into:

**Case 1 (altered)**: Dietetics, Fitness, And Health

**Case 2 (altered)**: Atmospheric Science

I'm finding it to be a bit tricky, though, because in one case, it's at the beginning of the phrase, and in the other, it's at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
preg_replace( '#/[a-z]+#i', '', $string);
```

You can see that it works [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/NhBahr).

What it does is uses a regular expression to find a `/` followed by one or more alphabetic characters. When it finds this, it replaces it with nothing (`''`).